# I can't get my div to use a fixed height. Have done extensive tests

Tags: html, css

On a note from my lecturer, using tables to make a nice, in-line layout isn't "Good coding practice". So, I switched to using divs which have been working fine for any *width* based issues, but:

There's no way for me to set the height to be static. I need to, in order to put my divs inline. Here's a screenshot of the website I am creating for my class: (cropped)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBUgo.png

When I was using tables for my layout, I was able to keep "News" and "Featured Product" in line, whereas with divs I cannot.

Here's what I've tried;
min-height with px or %, height with px or %, max-height with px or %, position: absolute, overflow: hidden, display: inline, display: inline-block, position: fixed, all taken from Stack Overflow "answers", and combinations of these.

I've also tried creating an empty (with one `<br />` tag) 100% width div, which would sit beneath the first two divs and above the last two, but for some reason this div is just chucked under my navigation bar to the top of the main container div, and it seems to not care about its placement relative to other divs in the code.

I'm using a css stylesheet, the four divs I am using are contained in a main div of class "container". Here's my *working* code;

```
.container {
    /* border: 2px solid red; /* For seeing the margins */
    margin-top: 3%;
}

.leftspacewide {
    /* border: 2px solid red; /* For seeing the margins */
    max-width: 74%;
    width: 74%;
    float: left;
}

.rightspacethin {
    /* border: 2px solid red; /* For seeing the margins */
    max-width: 24%;
    width: 24%;
    float: right;
}
```

And within my actual html, It's like this:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='leftspacewide'>
        welcome content here
    </div>
    <div class='rightspacethin'>
        login form here
    </div>
    <div class='leftspacewide'>
        featured product content here
    </div>
    <div class='rightspacethin'>
        news content here
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't get why every answer I read isn't working.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of your desired result?

Comment: @rpm192 https://i.imgur.com/AJ58oaF.png

Basically, the "Featured Product" text should be inline with "News". These are in separate divs. I figured to force them inline I could make the left and right side divs a fixed height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this structure with flex. It should work as expected. I have added colors to distinguish the 4 conatiners

```css
 

.container {
    /* border: 2px solid red; /* For seeing the margins */
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 3%;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.leftspacewide {
  width: 74%;
}
.rightspacethin {
  width: 26%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class='leftspacewide' style='background-color: red;'>
        welcome content here welcome content here welcome content here welcome content here welcome content herewelcome content herewelcome content herewelcome content herewelcome content herewelcome content herewelcome content herewelcome content herewelcome content herewelcome content herewelcome content here
    </div>
    <div class='rightspacethin' style='background-color: yellow;'>
        login form here             login form here             login form here             login form here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class='leftspacewide' style='background-color: blue;'>
        featured product content here             featured product content here             featured product content here             featured product content here             featured product content here
    </div>
    <div class='rightspacethin' style='background-color: green;'>
        news content here             news content here             news content here             news content here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that works just as I want it to!

I never knew about flex display.